# Outer Joins in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, outer-join, spark-structured-streaming

Is there a way to perform `outer_join` (specifically left outer join) in Spark Structured Streaming? I noticed this [JIRA #22053](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22053) that enables inner join for streaming datasets (and it works great!). I was wondering if there was something similar for `outer_join` as well. 
I tried using the same logic from the JIRA for outer join and haven't been able to get the right output. Thanks!

Comment: We've tried the same thing. We have successfully got left and inner to work with help from Databricks tech support. Outer is still elusive for us. Here is a jira ticket for it that is marked resolved for Spark version 2.3: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22136

Comment: Hi - When you say left, did you mean left outer join? Are you able to provide a sample with the left join, please? I've gotten inner to work. Left isn't working for me.

Comment: Spark 2.3 Stream-Stream Left outer join! I currently have this tested on databricks cluster. https://gist.github.com/jmwilli25/8d482c733196ffcb7850e300be56383d

Comment: There are 3 kinds outer join: left, right & full. What are you talking about? What is your problem? [mcve]. Clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the stream-stream Inner join and outer join working. Here's some sample code that I have. Hope it helps!

Stream-Stream Join ([JIRA Spark-22053](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22053) & [JIRA Spark-22136](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22136)):

`streamA.join(streamB, expr("streamA_ID = streamB_ID AND timeA BETWEEN timeB - INTERVAL 15 minutes and timeB"), joinType="{joinType}")`

The {joinType} can be either "inner", "leftOuter" or "rightOuter".

You can find more information on this in the article which will be published with Spark 2.3 release: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins

Comment: Hi I also try the stream to stream join spark 2.3  but I'm getting out off memory errors after some time, there is an open Jira regarding this issue SPARK-23682. Have you encountered this errors? Are you running structured streaming join from Kafka topics?

Answer (score 3):

Stream-stream join will be supported in Apache 2.3.0. Here are the document of 2.3.0 RC2: https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/spark/v2.3.0-rc2-docs/_site/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins

Comment: Hi! First of all Great Job on stream-stream joins! May I know how much work is it to support update mode? is it even planned for 2.4? I am not seeing any ticket related to that? because currently if I am not wrong in the case of outer joins user has to wait for the result until the watermark time elapses which typically can be hours or days (in my case). It would be nice to see partial joins at any given time so its more real time!

Comment: I was thinking if I should the add the update mode by myself by forking spark code. so I just wanted to know how much work would that be?